# Generate random alphanumeric string

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to generate a random code in vb.net like this

```
  Dim r As New Random
        Response.Write(r.Next())
```

But I want to generate code with 6 digits and should be alphanumeric like thie `A12RV1` and all codes should be like this.

I have tried vb.net random class but I am unable to do that like as I want. I want to get the alphanumeric code each time when I execute the code. How can i achieve this in vb.net?

Comment: The `Random` class is useful producing semi-random numbers.  In your case you are trying to generate a string of numbers and letters. The best approach is to generate 6 numbers and devise a method to convert them to one of the letters / numbers you want

Comment: Anyway, next time search in StackOverflow before posting a new question, because there was a lot of times asked before

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Function GetRandomString(ByVal iLength As Integer) As String
    Dim sResult As String = ""
    Dim rdm As New Random()

    For i As Integer = 1 To iLength
        sResult &= ChrW(rdm.Next(32, 126))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```

Or you can do the common random string defining the valid caracters:

```
Public Function GenerateRandomString(ByRef iLength As Integer) As String
    Dim rdm As New Random()
    Dim allowChrs() As Char = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".ToCharArray()
    Dim sResult As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To iLength - 1
        sResult += allowChrs(rdm.Next(0, allowChrs.Length))
    Next

    Return sResult
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will suits your requirement,

```
 Private sub GenerateString()

 Dim xCharArray() As Char = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray
 Dim xNoArray() As Char = "0123456789".ToCharArray
 Dim xGenerator As System.Random = New System.Random()
 Dim xStr As String = String.Empty

        While xStr.Length < 6

            If xGenerator.Next(0, 2) = 0 Then
                xStr &= xCharArray(xGenerator.Next(0, xCharArray.Length))
            Else
                xStr &= xNoArray(xGenerator.Next(0, xNoArray.Length))
            End If

        End While

        MsgBox(xStr)

 End Sub
```

**Note:** `Tested With IDE`

**EDIT:** `Modified according to SYSDRAGON's Comment`

Comment: You better do `While xStr.Length < 6`

Comment: And, anyway, "[You should never write code that relies on equivalent numeric values for True and False](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae382yt8.aspx)", you better do `If xGenerator.Next(0,2) = 0 Then`

Comment: @SysDragon Thanks for your tip, Actually i thought that comparring with equivalent numerical values for true and false was right, Its time to update in my project too, thanks!

Comment: @SysDragon we can use `if cbool(xGenerator.Next(0,2)) then` instead of your suggestion right.?

Comment: No. If you read the article on MSDN I commented before, you see the explanation.